# How to append the data to the existing json

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to check if the document with the entered userid exists. If it does I want to append just the ProjectName to the existing document file else I want to create a new document. Please help me with appending the data to the existing document.
Thank You in advance.

```
users.post('/createProject',function(Project, res, next){
  var Details = {
    User_Id:Project.body.userid,
    Project_Name: Project.body.ProjectName
  }
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("EMWorks");
    dbo.collection("projects").findOne(Project.body.userid)
      .then(user => {
        if(!user) {
          dbo.collection("projects").insertOne(Details, function(err, response) {
              if (err) throw err;
            console.log("***  DOCUMENTED INSERTED ***");
            res.send('Project Created');
          });
          }else{
            dbo.collection("projects").append(Details, function(err, response) {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log("***  Data Appended ***");
              res.send('Project Created');
            });
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.send('error: ' + err)
        })      
    });
})
```

Comment: Do you want to check for an user in `users` collection & do upsert in `projects` collection ?? why do you've have to do `.find()` in users collection rather you can do same in `projects` ? what's the difference ?

Comment: user is a variable in which the output of the findOne() is stored

Comment: my question is different !! Don't you have a field in projects collection which has value of `Project.body.userid` rather than checking for this in user collection ??

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not returning document back you can use [.updateOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html) with `upsert` else if you wanted to return document back use [.findOneAndUpdate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/index.html) , try below code :

```
users.post('/createProject', function (Project, res, next) {
    var Details = {
        User_Id: Project.body.userid,
        Project_Name: Project.body.ProjectName
    }
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("EMWorks");
        dbo.collection("projects").updateOne(
            { User_Id: Project.body.userid },
            { $set: { Project_Name: Project.body.ProjectName } },
            { upsert: true } 
            /** If no document matches with 'User_Id: Project.body.userid' then as specified 'upsert: true' will create a new document with filter & update parts combined. */
        ).then(resp => {
            if (resp.nupsertedId) {
                console.log("***  DOCUMENT INSERTED ***");
                res.send('Project Created');
            } else {
                console.log("***  Data Appended ***");
                res.send('Project Created');
            };
        }).catch(err => {
            res.send('error: ' + err)
        })
    });
})
```